# Question Regarding Logs specifically logs with $x$s involved

Tags: logarithms

$$\log(5x + 5) = 2\log(x + 1)$$

Thats the original question. So far I have gotten.

$$\log(5x + 5) = \log(x + 1)^2$$

I am not looking for the answer maybe just a hint in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: since you have $\log$ on both sides of the equation, take the inverse function of it.

Comment: So can I drop the log from both sides? ie 5x + 5 = (x + 1)^2

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

A logarithm is an injective function, which means that if $\log(a)=\log(b)$, then $a=b$.

Just be careful, that $\log(a)=\log(b)$ also implicitly means that $a,b>0$.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying I can drop the logs from both sides?

Comment: @JohnAllen Yes, as long as you are careful not to get any negative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about the negative solutions that would definately have caught me

Comment: @JohnAllen The safest way is to re-check your solution once you have it.